# pytest - make multiple tests operate on the same db

Tags: python, django, pytest

I am trying to avoid multiple creation of the same django object for multiple tests using `@pytest.fixture(scope='module')` syntax.

```
from bots.models import Bot


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def forwarding_bot():
    (bot, created) = Bot.objects.get_or_create(
        name="test_bot",
        user=get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='test_user'),
        forward_http_requests_to='https://httpbin.org/post'
    )
    return bot


def test_get_bot_by_pk(forwarding_bot):
    print(f'test_get_bot_by_pk: bot count: {Bot.objects.count()}')


def test_get_bot_by_uuid(forwarding_bot):
    print(f'test_get_bot_by_uuid: bot count: {Bot.objects.count()}')
```

When I run pytest I get this output:

```
test_get_bot_by_pk: bot count: 1
test_get_bot_by_uuid: bot count: 0
```

I understand the reason for this. The fixture function indeed gets fired once per module, but since its code creates a db object - only the first test finds it in DB.

The question is - how do I make several tests operate on the same db and the same fixture? I am new to pytest so this is a challenge to me.

Answer (score 0):

The way I approach for this problem is to create separate `testing.py` setting and giving it to `pytest.ini`;

```
# This setting is unit test only.

from .base import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
DEBUG = True
IS_TESTING = True
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'your_project' / 'testdb' / 'test_db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

then in your `router.py`;

```
class DatabaseRouter:

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        db_to_use = 'default'
        .
        .
        .
        if settings.IS_TESTING:
            db_to_use = 'default'

        return db_to_use

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        db_to_use = 'default'
        .
        .
        .
        if settings.IS_TESTING:
            db_to_use = 'default'

        return db_to_use

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if settings.IS_TESTING:
            return True

        return db == 'default'
```

And finally in `pytest.ini`;

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = your_project.settings.testing
addopts = --ds=your_project.settings.testing
python_files = tests.py */tests.py
```

This way, no matter how many databases you have, your tests will always use one database for testing.